# jVectorMap - Map with all countries

Tags: jvectormap

Can someone please help me with converting svg to jVectorMap. I can't get stroke to be smaller. I've tried so many things nothing had effect, editing with illustrator, removing stroke, adding stroke-width="1" to every `<g>, <path>` - no effect.

Map:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/BlankMap-Equirectangular.svg

Converter
http://svgto.jvectormap.com/

What i really need is a jVectorMap with all countries. Original is missing a lot of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found map for another similar plugin, and tweaked it a bit to work with jvector map. Hopefully it will help someone - here is the code, ready to use with jvector map.

https://gist.github.com/tomislavp83/3d2f860513a1dcb2ebd4

Comment: could you please upload it again? Thanks.@Tomek

Comment: Pleasse share site down